# showing up to a four-alarm fire with an eyedropper full of water

Tags: phrase-usage

Is the phrase "showing up to a four-alarm fire with an eyedropper full of water" a strong sarcasm? Or a very mild criticism?

I know how to express the situation using a Chinese idiom, which is a neutral or mild criticism.

> The New York Times Retweeted
> Sheryl Gay Stolberg tweeted:

Biden will send 60 million doses of AstraZeneca vaccine overseas as India crisis rages.
“That’s **showing up to a four-alarm fire with an eyedropper full of water**,” said
@asia_ilse @HealthGAP
Still no movement on waiving patent protections.

Source:  [Twitter](https://twitter.com/SherylNYT/status/1386845080099643392)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very strong sarcasm (*and* strong criticism). A “four-alarm fire”, or in general a [multiple-alarm fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-alarm_fire), is a raging inferno. The name comes from the alarm bells that would ring in a fire station — more bells means more fire trucks were called to the scene.

So showing up to such a disaster with an eyedropper full of water (a few milliliters at most) would be laughably inadequate.

Comment: I don't know that it's *sarcasm* as much as *an analogy*.

Comment: It's definitely not a mild criticism.

Comment: I would consider this "the use of irony to mock or convey contempt".